# how to access jar file residing in WEB-INF/lib in JUNIT test case

Tags: java, spring, junit

I need to access a jar file residing in WEB-INF/lib in JUnit Test case.
In a normal java file that resides in any jar, I am able to get the current jar via: 
`this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`

However when I run it via JUnit test case, it returns the location in workspace where Test class file resides.

How can I get the access the same jar file via JUNIT.

I even tried with a particular class (XYZ.class) that resides in WEB-INF/lib/abc.jar as follows:
 `XYZ.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`  but it also returns the workspace path where Test class file resides.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to access a jar file that  is in the classpath?

Comment: Jar file contains resources that needs to be accessed

Comment: Then you just need `SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream()`, and the class loader will load it for you.